# Retaining default values for both dropdown values after executing ng-change on first dropdown list to get option values for second dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Only the hospital dropdown code is displaying "HOSPITAL 1" in the dropdown display but the ward dropdown code is not displaying "WARD 1" like it should when I refresh the page.

Everytime I refresh the page it will call ng-change from hospital dropdown and retrieve the respective wards according to the hospital selected which is "HOSP1" but the display for the ward dropdown will be set as "Please Select Ward" instead of "WARD1".

I tried to retain the old wardCode == 'WARD1' like I did for hosp in the controller but to no avail as the value changes after the ng-change is fired.

Does anyone know if I can use angular copy in this scenario?

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Hosp</label>
<select ng-model='search.hosp'select-options=" {{hosp}}" select-data=" 
{{search.hospCode}}" ng-change="wardDropdown()" id="hospCode" 
name="hospCode">

    <option value="">Please Select Hosp</option>
    <option ng-repeat="obj in hosp" value="{{obj.VALUE}}">{{obj.LABEL}} 
</option>
</select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Ward</label>
    <select ng-model='search.wardCode' select-options="{{wards}}" 
    select-data="{{search.wards}}" id="wardCode" name="wardCode">

        <option value="">Please Select Ward</option>
        <option ng-repeat="obj in wards" value="{{obj.VALUE}}"> 
        {{obj.LABEL}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.search = {}
$scope.search.hosp = 'HOSP1';
$scope.search.wardCode = 'WARD1';

//Start, hosp dropdown list
$scope.hosp = function () {
var url = /searchHosp',
method = methodType.POST,
    functionName = 'searchHosp',
    params = {};

if (data.status == messageStatus.success) {
    $scope.hospitals = data.result;

} else {
    $scope.errorMessage = promptMessage.searchRecordFailure;
}
},
function (error) {
    $scope.errorMessage = promptMessage.exception;
    )
};
$scope.hospitalList();
//End, hosp dropdown 

//Start, ward dropdown 
$scope.wardDropdown = function () {
var url = searchWard,
    method = methodType.POST,
    functionName = 'searchWard',
    params = {};
    params.hosp = $scope.search.hosp;

if (data.status == messageStatus.success) {
    $scope.wards = data.result;
}
} 
else {
$scope.errorMessage = promptMessage.searchRecordFailure;
}

$scope.wardDropdown();

//End, ward dropdown list
```